# state change and packet loss

Tags: algorithm, networking, udp, lag

Let's say I want to speed up networking in a real-time game by sending only changes in position instead of absolute position.  How might I deal with packet loss? If one packet is dropped the position of the object will be wrong until the next update.

Comment: Use TCP/IP instead of UDP if you can't tolerate packet loss...

Comment: @Floris That just doesn't scale.  Many MMORPGs have to deal with this *very* thing and they do it over UDP.

Answer (score 0):

Reflecting on @casperOne's comment, this is one reason why some games go "glitchy" over poor connections.

A possible solution to this is as follows:

1. Decide on the longest time you can tolerate an object/player being displayed in the wrong location - say `xx` ms. Put a watchdog timer in place that sends location of an object "at least" every xx ms, or whenever a new position is calculated.
2. Depending on the quality of the link, and the complexity of your scene, you can shorten the value of xx. Basically, if you are not using available bandwidth, start sending current position of the object that has not had an update sent the longest.

To do this you need to maintain a list of items in the order you have updated them, and rotate through it.

That means that fast changes are reflected immediately (if object updates every ms, you will probably get a packet through quite often so there is hardly any lag), but it never takes more then xx ms before you get another chance at having an updated state.